# why does not jupyter notebook open?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run jupyter notebook, but all the time is crushing, and it closes automatically.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 235, in _resolve_classes
klass = self._resolve_string(klass)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2009, in _resolve_string
return import_item(string)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 30, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.contents'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 285, in launch_instance
return super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1044, in launch_instance
app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 555, in instance
inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1295, in __new__
inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1338, in setup_instance
super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1314, in setup_instance
init(self)
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 226, in instance_init
self._resolve_classes()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py", line 238, in _resolve_classes
warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it installed?", ImportWarning)
TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'stacklevel'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving to a previous version of traitlets by doing these steps :-

```
pip uninstall traitlets

pip install traitlets==5.9.0
```